# Simplify Double Integral Joint Density

Tags: probability, integration, multivariable-calculus, probability-distributions

$f(x, y) = Axe^{-x(y+1)^2}$ for $x > 0$ and $y > 0$, $0$ otherwise. To solve for $A$, I have:
$$1=\int_{0}^{\infty}\int_{0}^{\infty}Axe^{-x\left(y+1\right)^{2}}dxdy$$ But I do not know how to simplify this integral.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can rewrite the integral in the following way

$$\underbrace{\int_0^{\infty}[x(y+1)^2]e^{-x(y+1)^2}d[x(y+1)^2]}_{\int_0^{\infty}ue^{-u}du=1}\int_0^{\infty}\frac{1}{(y+1)^4}dy=\int_0^{\infty}\frac{1}{(y+1)^4}dy=$$

$$=-\frac{(y+1)^{-3}}{3}\Bigg|_{y=0}^{y=\infty}=\frac{1}{3}$$

Thus $$A=3$$

Answer (score 0):

Let $t >0$ Integrating by parts we get $\int_0^{\infty} xe^{-tx}dx=-\frac 1 t xe^{-tx}|_0^{\infty} +\frac1  t\int_0^{\infty} e^{-tx} dx=\frac1  {t^{2}}$. Hence, taking $t=(y+1)^{2}$ we get  $1=A\int_0^{\infty} \frac 1 {({y+1})^{4}} dy$. Can you continue?